# how to render var? or two components together? var output is not showing

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i am facing this error var helloworld is not printing?
 h2 is not printing hello world only h1 is printing helloword 2times why var is not printing ????
    how two render two components together?

```
  var h2=React.createElement('h2',null,'Hello World')
    ReactDOM.render(
        h2,document.getElementById('content')
    )

    //but this code is not printing hello world ?


    let h1=React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')
    class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return React.createElement('div',null,h1,h1)
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(HelloWorld, null),
        document.getElementById('content')
    )
    //this code is printing  two times hello world
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but you are in fact rendering the same component (`h1` in this case) twice `React.createElement('div',null,h1,h1)`. not to mention both of your components render the same text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var h2=React.createElement('h2',null,'Hello World')
    ReactDOM.render(
        h2,document.getElementById('content')
    )
```

this method works fine for me.

for the second method you are passing two `h1` components as children for the newly created component. `React.cloneElement( element, [props], [...children] )`. hence two h1 is rendered as children.

to render both `h1` and `h2` please try the following

```
var h2=React.createElement('h2',null,'Hello World')
let h1=React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return React.createElement('div',null,h2,h1)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(HelloWorld, null),
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q0weL46u/

React.creatElement is an old way. I recommend using JSX to describe your component. as given below

https://jsfiddle.net/j5wj7kfn/